# make command does not existed

Tags: wireless

So i just installed ubuntu 17.10,and ubuntu don't come with my netgear a6210 wifi driver,so i have to use make command to compile it.but make command is gone.and when i try to install make,it just said Package ‘make‘ has no installation candidate.i don't have an ethernet cable either,at this point idk what i should do,since i can't install wifi driver

Comment: In terminal `history | tail` and edit the question to include the results

Answer (score 1):

You must not have `build-essential` installed. Please try this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```